# Trying to create a windows batch script that loops through only a certain level of directories in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a number of excel files nested in separate folders in a directory.  Each of these folders also has any number of other files, but I am only interested in the excel files.  I am trying to copy all the excel files into a new folder.

What I have been able to create is this.

`for /r "C:\Folder One\Folder Two" %%f in (*.xls, *.xlsm) do @copy "%%f" "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\New Excel Folder"`

The problem is, each of the subdirectories may have another one or two folders which may or may not have an errant excel file that I am not interested in.  My solution grabs every single excel file in the entire directory structure.

I am looking for a way to only get the excel files from all of the the third level down folders, so everything in c:\Folder One\Folder Two\THESE FOLDERS AT THIS LEVEL, but no deeper.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You should be able to do everything you want with a single `ROBOCOPY` command as it has this option: `/LEV:n :: only copy the top n LEVels of the source directory tree.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

for /r "%sourcedir%" %%f in (*.xls, *.xlsm) do FOR /F "tokens=4,5delims=\" %%q IN ("%%~dpf") DO IF "%%r"=="" FOR %%e IN (.xls .xlsm) DO IF /i "%%e"=="%%~xf" ECHO @copy "%%f" "%destdir%"

GOTO :EOF
```

I've changed directorynames to suit my test setup.

The `@copy` command is `echo`ed for verification. Remove the `ECHO` to actually execute the `copy`.

Two stages in the filtering. First, check the number of `\` characters in the filepath - `%%r` will be non-empty when the required directory-level is exceeded. The filename is then checked explicitly for the required extensions because `filename.xlsx` will have an automatically-by-default short filename generated which will match `.xls`.

---

Tokens:

`delims=\xyz"` defines a delimiter character-set of `["\","x","y","z"]`. I always place the `delims=` option last so that any characters appearing between `delims=` and `"` are included in the delimiter character-set.

The string under examination is viewed as

[[delimiter-sequence]][token1][delimiter-sequence][token2][delimiter-sequence][token3][delimiter-sequence][token4][delimiter-sequence][token5]...

where a delimiter-sequence is a sequence of *any* of the delimiters. The initial delimiter-sequence is optional.

So, with `delimiters` set to `\` *alone*, a sample string, `c:\Folder One\Folder Two\THESE FOLDERS AT THIS LEVEL\but no .deeper`

will be parsed as

Token 1 `c:`
Token 2 `Folder One`
Token 3 `Folder Two`
Token 4 `THESE FOLDERS AT THIS LEVEL`
Token 5 `but no .deeper`
Token 6 *empty*

However, the code I posted applied the `for ...%%q` to `%%~dpf`, not `%%f` nor `%%~dpnxf` nor `%%~ff` so the string to be parsed was `c:\Folder One\Folder Two\THESE FOLDERS AT THIS LEVEL\` where Token 5 would be empty. Had there been an extra directory-level, then Token 5 would not be empty.

I'd suggest that either a stray delimiter has been introduced, or some string other than `%%~dpf` is being parsed.

I never use `%%f` for filename, regardless of its original attractiveness, as `f` is a metavariable-modifier and subject to typos.

Comment: Thank you.  I will need to test this out later today, but it looks promising!

Comment: Worked almost perfectly!  The only change I had to make was changing delims from 5 to 6.  Don't ask me why as I am not sure I understand the tokens and delims at this point.  It works as I need it to with that slight change.  Thank you!